# php echo text after array of posts. But not after last one

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, blogs

I have created an array of post results. After each post I need to add the following characters "/!" which I have done using the echo function. However, those characters can't exist after the last post (or before the first post) before anyone suggests echoing it before.

Is there a way to not have this echoed if the post is the last one?

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
<?php 
echo '[wpic]';
$my_query = new WP_Query( "category_name=editorial&posts_per_page=-1" ); if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
the_post_thumbnail(array(400,400));
    echo '/!';
endwhile; endif;
echo '[/wpic]';
} 
?>
```

Where [wpic] is a shortcode to create a slideshow. But each image needs to be proceeded by '/!'

Comment: Will `implode()` function help you?

Comment: Show us what you have done ?

Comment: give us some code, espacially the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

echo '[wpic]';
$my_query = new WP_Query( "category_name=editorial&posts_per_page=-1" ); 

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 

    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $my_query->the_post();
        the_post_thumbnail(array(400,400));

        if (($my_query->current_post +1 )< $my_query->post_count)
            echo '/!';

    endwhile; 
endif;

echo '[/wpic]';

} 
?>
```

It's in the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts) for `have_posts()`

Comment: I have just tried this, and it's still outputting '/!' after the last post (just before echoing [/wpic]). Any reason why this might be?

Comment: @SamSkirrow - edited it again, it should of course count the posts in your current query.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a for loop:

```
$max = 10;
for($i=0; $i<=$max; $i++)
{
  if($i != $max) echo "/!";
}
```

Comment: I see how this would work. But Can it work for an indefinite amount of posts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if( ($wp_query->current_post + 1) < ($wp_query->post_count) ) {
    echo '/!';
};
```

see http://wp-snippets.com/check-if-last-post/